# Packaging an epub with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a small nodejs app that unpacks an epub, modifies the title, then repackages it.

Unpacking and modifying work. When I repackage, with the npm package 'archiver', the archived file appears to be corrupted. It cannot be opened by an eReader or unpackaged by a compression utility.

If I package the directory using the same code in a stand-alone js file, it works fine.

Inside the main app, I use the following to call each module (unzip, rename, rezip). As far as I can tell, this is the only difference between the code in this app (which doesn't work) vs the code in the stand alone file (which does).

```
var unzip = require('../services/unzip');
var replacetitle = require('../services/replacetitle');
var rezip = require('../services/rezip');    

fileObject = {};
fileObject.unzipPath = "/Users/me/Downloads/myPath/";
fileObject.filePath = "/Users/me/Downloads";
fileObject.novelTitle = "myFile";

unzip.unzip(fileObject)
    .then( 
        replacetitle.replacetitle(fileObject) 
    ).then(
        rezip.rezip(fileObject)
    );
```

Here's the code from rezip.js (not working):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var archiver = require("archiver");

module.exports = {
    rezip: function(fileObject){

        var path = fileObject.unzipPath;
        var outputPath = fileObject.filePath + '/' + fileObject.novelTitle + '.epub';
        var output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
        var archive = archiver("zip");

        // pipe archive data to the file
        archive.pipe(output);

        // add the mimetype file.  This MUST be the first file added
        archive.file(path + "mimetype", { name: "mimetype" });

        // append the other files and folders
        var files = fs.readdirSync(path);

        // Loop through each item in the directory, determine if
        // it is a file or a directory and append accordingly
        function fileAppender(fileIndex) {
            if (fileIndex < files.length) {
                var stat = fs.statSync(path + files[fileIndex]);
                if (stat.isFile()) {
                    if (
                        files[fileIndex] !== "mimetype" &&
                        files[fileIndex] !== ".DS_Store"
                    ) {
                        archive.file(path + files[fileIndex], { name: files[fileIndex] });
                    }
                } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    archive.directory(path + files[fileIndex], files[fileIndex]);
                }
                fileAppender(fileIndex + 1);

            } else {
                // finalize the archive (ie we are done appending files but streams have to finish yet)
                // 'close', 'end' or 'finish' may be fired right after calling this method so register to them beforehand
                archive.finalize();
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    resolve(fileObject);
                })
            }
        }
        fileAppender(0);
    }
}
```

Below is the code from the stand alone file that works. Watching each of these in the debugger, they execute the same way, only one outputs a file that can be opened with an eReader or an archive utility, while the other outputs a file that seems corrupted.

```
fileObject = {
    path: "/Users/me/Downloads/myPath/",
    outputPath: "/Users/me/Downloads/myPath/myFile.epub"
}
var fs = require("fs");
var archiver = require("archiver");

var path = fileObject.path;
var outputPath = fileObject.outputPath;
var output = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
var archive = archiver("zip");

// pipe archive data to the file
archive.pipe(output);

// add the mimetype file.  This MUST be the first file added
archive.file(path + "mimetype", { name: "mimetype" });

// append the other files and folders
var files = fs.readdirSync(path);

// Loop through each item in the directory, determine if
// it is a file or a directory and append accordingly
function fileAppender(fileIndex) {
    if (fileIndex < files.length) {
        var stat = fs.statSync(path + files[fileIndex]);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            if (
                files[fileIndex] !== "mimetype" &&
                files[fileIndex] !== ".DS_Store"
            ) {
            archive.file(path + files[fileIndex], { name: files[fileIndex] });
            }
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            archive.directory(path + files[fileIndex], files[fileIndex]);
        }
        fileAppender(fileIndex + 1);
    } else {
        // finalize the archive (ie we are done appending files but streams have to finish yet)
        // 'close', 'end' or 'finish' may be fired right after calling this method so register to them beforehand
        archive.finalize();
    }
}
fileAppender(0);
```

I've tested setting the paths rather than passing them in the fileObject object, but I got the same results.

I'm new to nodejs.

Comment: Maybe [this project](https://github.com/LastLeaf/epub-generator) is of help to you, especially this part: https://github.com/LastLeaf/epub-generator/blob/master/lib/builder.js#L22-L89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to not handling the promises correctly. Everything works if I don't use a promise chain and just manually run them as individual scripts. Looks like I really just need to become more familiar with promises.